# How to solve _netrc file issue while using NASAaccess package?

Tags: r, .netrc

I wish to use the NASAaccess tool in R. I have installed the curl software in my system, and also have created the _netrc file in the home directory as instructed (including teh _netrc, .netrc, .urscookie). However when I try to run the code it asks to create the netrc files in the home directory which I have already done. What should be the problem here?

I re-installed the curl software, re-wrote the files in the home directory, praded the R version. It should have worked by now providing the rainfall data output.

Answer (score 0):

NASAaccess version 3.4.0 and newer has been developed with an added automated script for netrc file creation. Upon working with NASAaccess, the user registration access logging information obtained from https://www.earthdata.nasa.gov/ will be processed by masking (i.e., not displaying the literal typed text as input) on most but not all platforms. Without providing user registration access logging information, the user will receive ‘You need to provide your Earthdata GES DISC login to proceed…’ message.